# Increment of integer PK values by 1 doesn't throw duplicate key error. Why?

Tags: sql-server

As stated in the title I am wondering why the following piece of code will note fail with duplicate key error. As a result of the following test, obviously, the update does not check for duplicity after each row. What happens inside? Is this part of the standard of just SQL Server specific behavior? Thanks!

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
    x INT PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (2)

UPDATE @T SET x = x + 1;

-- DUPLICATE KEY ERROR EXPECTED.

SELECT * FROM @T;

--- VALUES HAVE BEEN INCREMENTED. NO ERROR THROWN.
```

Comment: Were you using MySQL before?

Comment: I was, but I dont think that I have every encountered it. From what I understand the error would be thrown in MySQL as part of its non-ANSI behavior. Thank you for the fiddle, however the link does not seem to work.

Comment: I have corrected the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The checks (about `UNIQUE`, `PRIMARY KEY` and other, `NOT NULL` and `CHECK` constraints) are done after the whole `UPDATE` statement has finished. This is the expected behaviour in SQL. Operations/statements are performed on sets (of rows), not on each row individually.**<sup>(*)</sup>**

And while for `NOT NULL` and `CHECK` constraints, it doesn't matter if the checking is done after each row change or after the whole statement, for unique constraints (`UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY KEY`) it does matter.

In fact, the SQL standard has 2 options. The checks are either done after the statement (when the constraint is `NOT DEFERRABLE`) or even later, at the end of the transaction (when the constraint is `DEFERRABLE`) and the statement is part of a transaction.

SQL-Server supports only `NOT DEFERRABLE` constraints, so checks are after every statement and not at the end of transactions.

---

**(*)**
Perhaps you have been used to MySQL, which shows this non-standard behaviour, checking constraints after each row update (or insert.) See the [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20bd7/1) where the update fails (if you change the DBMS from SQL-Server to MySQL.)

Comment: See also Halloween Problem - [wikipedia article][1] and a [more academic paper][2] - ensuring that an update occurs just once to each row.


  [1]:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_Problem
  [2]:http://web.archive.org/web/20070718223542/http://www.noncombatant.org/trove/fitzpatrick-anecdotes.pdf